# Why did the Terminator shoot its own foot to escape the trap?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-salvation

In *Terminator Salvation* movie, a terminator gets caught in a trap so that it is dangling upside down.

Instead of shooting the cable holding it upside down, it shoots its own foot.

Why not shoot the cable, or pull itself up and release the cable around its foot?

Comment: Because it's a robo-schmuck

Comment: How do you imagine it hitting a 1 cm^2 surface with _that_ gun? Besides, it seemed to walk just as good without the foot. Also, +1 for Anton Yelchin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_Salvation_(novel)), we learn that the T-600, frustrated by its inability to shoot the cable, decided to aim for a larger target, its own foot.

> *On the street outside, **the stymied T-600 fired twice at the cable that had wrapped around its right foot. Most shells missed the gleaming, slender target. Those that struck it glanced off. Responding to the overriding resolve of its pursuit programming, it proceeded to shoot off the restraining foot.** Thus freed, it slammed into the pavement below with enough force and weight to buckle the old concrete.
>
>   Proceeding to right itself, it limped toward the entrance to the factory.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator Salvation - Official Novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_Salvation_(novel))</sup></sub>

In the film you see it aiming at the cable for a brief second before it starts blasting away at its foot.

Comment: It fired multiple times at a target less than a meter away and still missed most of the time? Sheesh! That rusty old bucket of bolts doesn't deserve the name, terminator.

Comment: @RichS - It's not designed to terminate small pieces of wire.

Comment: Off topic, but that prose is not how I remember Alan Dean Foster…

Comment: @tobiasvl - Based on a brief read-through, my guess is that he crapped this one out in less than a fortnight.

Comment: @Valorum Let's compare the two targets. The cable doesn't move, doesn't fight back, has no brains, has no weapons, and was less than a meter away. A human moves, evades, fights back, has weapons, and has a brain. If the terminator can't win against a cable, how's it gonna win against a person?

Comment: @RichS: It was an old model, probably had something in its sensors that it could not get out of its focus (everything was super dusty/dirty from the war) and needed a large target to shoot at to get back at its target.